# How to insert my values to identity and non identity field using single query

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
use regimen
SET IDENTITY_INSERT data ON 
insert into data (firstname,lastname,quantity,rollno) 
values ('yLMdxMRqUuwCWQMzfXeqhdymQDOaiBKSvYLUBigGHLfYHKwof','hEezSvnAnUYRgsKDhYeSXWQxJwXz','858437.74','98834') 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT data OFF
```

Hi this is my problem:

Here am randomly inserting strings and integer to the fields in the column.
like that while am inseting integer if the integer field is Identity(auto increment)]mean this query works perfect

but the fiels is not an identity(auto increment) mean it not work i got error not able to perform set opertation nu...so i want to insert integer for both Identity and non identity fields how to do that?

if i wantto insert identity field want to perform set operation on and off
non identity field no need to perform set operation

how to use both work in single query?how to modify my query?

anybody say the correct query for dynamically passingIinserting) integer for an identity and non identity fields?

Comment: i have no idea what you are asking here...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is clear

1. You can't use SET IDENTITY_INSERT without an IDENTITY column.
2. Either you have an IDENTITY column or you don't
3. If you don't, add an IDENTITY column
4. If you don't want to add an IDENTITY column, then don't use SET IDENTITY_INSERT
5. If you want to use SET IDENTITY_INSERT you need an IDENTITY column

So go back to step 1 and repeat...